# How many questions are asked every second on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, statistics

Not sure if this question belongs here but I want to give it a shot.

I need to give a presentation about Q&A websites and, of course, I cannot do this without mentioning the Stack Exchange community. I wanted to show some statistics about Stack Exchange and mention how many questions are asked every second (or minute).

However, I looked around but haven't found a good answer.

Can someone point out to me where I can find such information?

Comment: You can find stats *per site* by running queries on http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Nice feature, thanks!

Comment: Sample query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/14647/number-of-questions-per-day. Use the 'switch sites' selector to get the number for various sites. The [sites listing](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) gives you questions per day stats too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the answer by Shadow Wizard: of course we can [add numbers in JavaScript, even without jQuery][1]. Navigate to [stackexchange.com/sites][2] and paste the following into the browser console:

```
l=document.getElementsByTagName('input'); s=0; for (i=0;i<l.length;i++) {if (l[i].name=='questions-per-day') {s += parseFloat(l[i].value,10);} }
```

This returns the number of questions per day across the network (averaged over the last two weeks). Current value: `9739.35714285715`. Divide by 24, then by 60: the result is about 6.76 questions per minute.

---

One can also study fluctuations of the rate of asking (and answering) throughout the day by using API. For example [this API query][3] currently returns for Stack Overflow:

```
"answers_per_minute": 4.22,
"questions_per_minute": 2.45
```

These are updated about once per hour, if I understand the API documentation correctly.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif
[2]: https://stackexchange.com/sites
[3]: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow&filter=!8IekO(4rcREPrPHKR5-iD

Comment: You can use jQuery, it's included in all pages and the console has the page context.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I originally wanted to, but decided not to, out of sheer principle. :)

Comment: Fine, make your life harder by choice. :-D

Comment: Oh, I see how it works. No jQuery & no freehand circles => 1 upvote vs 10 for the other post. (And that 1 probably was Shadow himself, a known good sport...)

Comment: I think you just cracked the super secret Meta formula of voting! Or, maybe Meta dwellers simply don't like scripting, as [this awesome script of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236948/152859) got a meager single upvote. And yes, you guessed right. :-D

Answer (score 11):

As can be seen in the [sites lists on stackexchange.com portal](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest), for Stack Overflow:

> [image]

There are 7354 posted every day, in average. Each day contains 86400 seconds, so it's 0.085 questions per second or more human friendly form, a question is posted once every 11.5 seconds.

You can do the same calculation for other sites individually, but you'll have to sum your results to get the figure for the network as a whole.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for some reason thought he want only Stack Overflow.