# Pagination of network-wide inbox is evil and buggy

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox, network-profile, pagination

Network-wide inbox has a lot of pages. The number of pages in my inbox must be tiny by comparison with the users who were active for years, but here is the illustration anyway:

[image: buttons]

If I want to get back to messages from June, I have some clicking to do. And unlike every other paginated list on Stack Exchange, this one *does not insert page parameter into the URL*. Otherwise I'd be able to change the parameter to something like `page=30` and get in the vicinity of the time period I want. Hence, a feature request:

- Use `page` URL parameter for pagination of network-wide inbox

Also, a bug. If I right-click a page number and open it in a new tab, I get an unstyled page:

[image: nostyle]

Now I do have the page parameter I can change. But no stylesheet to go with it.

Comment: No bug, it's simply loading the contents using AJAX.

Comment: If opening a visible link in a new tab results in an unstyled page... I'd still say it's a bug.

Comment: Still don't think so, and anyway better split this into a separate report.

Comment: Agree, this is really annoying. The normal user pages manage to use ajax loading *and* set URL parameters that allow reloading and forward/back navigation - this page should behave the same way.

Comment: Sorry for your rep loss and thanks for preferring me over the void ;-)

Comment: Bug is now fixed too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Switching between pages in the inbox now appends a `?tab=inbox&page=#` to the URL for easier pagination.

The pagination links also now correctly point to the same page, so right clicking and opening in a new tab/window won't take you to an unstyled page anymore.

Comment: So, to which dev do we owe a beer? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Kevin Montrose did both of these. :)

Answer (score 6):

Workaround to load specific page is pasting the following into JavaScript console of the browser:

```javascript
var desiredPage = 12;
var desiredLink = $("#inbox-pager").find("a").first().attr("href").split("=")[0] + "=" + desiredPage;
$("#inbox-container").load(desiredLink, function () { $.scrollTo($("#inbox-container")); });
```

Just change the desired page, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you're done. :)